# Advanced Pointers

Tags: c

Output:

```
TEST  
sQuiz  
Z  
CQ
```

No entiendo por que da esos valores de salida este código:

```
char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;

    printf("%s ", **++cpp); 
    printf("%s ", *--*++cpp+3);
    printf("%s ", *cpp[-2]+3);
    printf("%s ", cpp[-1][-1]+1);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuáles son los valores de salida que esperas? Recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario, usando el enlace Editar bajo las etiquetas. Así puedes añadir toda la información adicional que se requiera para responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Simplemente esta jugando con los punteros. Si quieres entenderlo tienes que descpomoner que es lo que hace cada accion

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Cuál de los cuatro casos no entiendes?

Answer (score 1):

Es muy fácil, simplemente fíjate en cómo se están guardando los punteros.

Primero `char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};` lo puedes ver como un arreglo 2D, pero si tomamos que `char []` es una cadena de texto nos podemos imaginar que `char *c[]` es un arreglo 1D de "strings"

Después se define `char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};` que si te das cuenta es un puntero a un puntero de un arreglo, y en este caso sólo es un puntero a los punteros de `char *c[]`.

Y los valores que tiene `cp` son los punteros de `char *c` pero en orden contrario.

- c + 3 hace referencia a `c[3]` o sea en ese puntero está el valor de `"Quiz"` y esto se va a almancenar en `cp[0]`
- c + 2 hace referencia a `c[2]` o sea en ese puntero está el valor de `"TEST"` y esto se va a almancenar en `cp[1]`

Y así con los demás

`char ***cpp = cp` Es lo mismo que `char **cp[]`, ya que un arreglo reserva espacio de memoria pero lo que guarda es un puntero al primer espacio de memoria reservado.

- `**++cpp` lo podemos rescribir así `**(++cpp)` y dividir así:

  1. `++cpp` -> el puntero de `cpp` se recorre en 1 o sea es el equivalente de `&(cpp[1]) = &(cp + 1)` (Fíjate que se actualiza el puntero de cpp)
  2. `**(1)` hace dos derreferencias en la primera accede a `cp + 1 = &(cp[1])` en la segunda accede ya a `cp[1]` que si te das cuenta es igual a `*(c + 2) = c[2]` que es igual a `"TEST"`
- `*--*++cpp+3` es más confuso, por lo que lo reescribiremos a `(*(--(*(++cpp)))) + 3`

  1. `++cpp` -> el puntero de `cpp` se recorre en 1 o sea es el equivalente de `&(cpp[2]) = &(cp + 2)` (Se actualiza el puntero de cpp) y en este momento está posicionado en `&&(c[1])`
  2. Se derrefencía y estamos posicionados en `&(c[1])`
  3. Se restamos un espacio de memoria al puntero con `--(2)` y nos posicionamos en `&(c[0])`
  4. Accedemos a ese espacio de memoria al derrefenciar con `*(3)` y ahora estamos en c[1]
  5. A ese arreglo (puntero) le sumamos 3, indicándole que se salte 3 letras por eso imprime `"sQuiz"` y no `"GeksQuiz"`

Las otras dos ya están más sencillas, te invito a hacerlas tú mismo y responder en os comentarios o en otra respuesta si le has logrado ;)

**EDIT**

Algo importante de notar es esta parte `&(cpp[2]) = &(cp + 2)` de la explicación del segundo `printf()`, ese dos es porque `++` le aumentó `+1` en el primer `printf()` y en el segundo `printf()` se lo estamos volviendo a aumentar.